# ActiveX not shown in Manage add on

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, activex

I have built an ActiveX control for x86 version of IE, which registers & runs correctly. I can install it on other x86 machines and it works fine as well. I am not getting any errors, just that it doesn't appear in IE's Tools->Manage add-ons. Other machines will get the yellow bar at the top of IE, but once accepted it does not re-appear.

Do i need to add something in the RC file for this?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft does not want you to modify their product, thats why activex or any other addons by microsoft will not show up. Of you want to modify activex, then search activex in my computer.

Comment: I am not trying to modify any other ActiveX dll. I have created my own to run in IE.